# WPF targeting .NET 4.5 but windows asking to install .NET 3.5 when the app run

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have WPF app targeting .NET 4.5 but anytime I lunch the app this dialog popup.

here are my app.config settings

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

[image]

How to stop showing this dialog?
Is it required to install .NET 3.5 while targeting .NET 4.5?

This is happening on windows 10, didn't test for others.
And the app run and work correctly without installing .NET 3.5

Comment: Righ click on your project.  Go to Properties. Check that the Target Framework is the correct version.

Comment: Please check my answer as it might actually solve your problem. Please mark as answered if it does.

Comment: @Darkonekt The Target Framework is 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your operating system is Windows 8 or does not have .NET 2.0.....

And your code depends in any way on .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5.....

Than it means it NEEDS .NET  2.0 to run.

Thus it will prompt you to install .NET 3.5.

This is documented by microsoft:

> Windows 8 Behavior and UI
>   The CLR activation system provides the same behavior and UI on Windows 8 as it does on other versions of the Windows operating system, except when it encounters issues loading CLR 2.0. Windows 8 includes the .NET Framework 4.5, which uses CLR 4.5. However, Windows 8 does not include the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5, which all use CLR 2.0. As a result, applications that depend on CLR 2.0 do not run on Windows 8 by default. Instead, they display the following dialog box to enable users to install the .NET Framework 3.5. Users can also enable the .NET Framework 3.5 in Control Panel.

Scroll almost all the way to the bottom of this article to the title:
[**Windows 8 Behavior and UI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/initialization-errors-managing-the-user-experience)

Comment: My app run perfectly without installing anything, the dialog just popup

Comment: What do you mean by 'And your code depends in any way on .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5.....' ? you mean my nugget deficiencies ?

Comment: Gorel. I mean that if any dependencies you have use framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 specific functionality.... then it will popup that message.  Because those versions of the framework depend on 2.0.... While 4.0 and up do not.